# Generate sequence in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, interval

I want to generate a sequence using Linq that goes from 10 to 100 with a step size of 10. The sequence also must contain a custom value (in the correct order).

This is what I have now, and I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of doing it using Linq expressions.

```
var pageSize = 25; //number that must be in sequnce if not already, can be anything.
var items = Enumerable.Range(10, 100)     //Generate range           
           .Where(x => x % 10 == 0)       //Take every 10th item
           .Concat(new[] { pageSize })    //Add the custom number
           .Distinct()                    //If the custom number was already in there, remove it
           .OrderBy(x => x);              //Sort the sequence
```

Result:

```
10 
20 
25 
30 
40 
50 
60 
70 
80 
90 
100
```

Comment: Why should the result include 25?

Comment: @200_success Could be 25 or any other integer. This code is used to generate the datasource to a drop down to select the page size of a GridView. The custom number (25 in the case) is the page size currently set on the gridview and I need to include that in the sequence as that value is set as the default selected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Know your library

**`.Distinct()`** should immediately make you think of a **`Set`**.
**`.OrderBy(...)`** should make you think of a sorted collection.

I give you: the [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), part of .NET since version 4.0.

## When LINQ is not enough, extend it

LINQ uses [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), so if it doesn't have what you need, add your own:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> ToSelectionWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, params T[] items)
{
    return new SortedSet<T>(sequence.Concat(items));
}
```

## Usage

This allows you to call it as though it were a part of LINQ itself:

```
var pageSize = 25;
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x*10).ToSelectionWith(pageSize);
```

## Benefits

1. **It's concise** — a one-liner. You could even skip the extension method and use the `SortedSet` directly.
2. **It's readable** — by wrapping it in the extension method, the intent of using the `SortedSet` is clarified.
3. **It performs well** — in my crude `Stopwatch` testing, it beat your and Sandeep's versions for both small and large input sequences. (Specifically, the `SortedSet` based approach runs twice as fast as Sandeep's version for your original input, and at least three times as fast for very large input sizes).

Comment: I disagree with your second point. It is not readable at all. If i were to see the line of code from your usage example, i would assume that it adds an element to enumeration. Certainly not that it both _sorts_ and _distincts_ it as well. You extension method does not indicate the usage of `SortedSet` in its implementation in any way.

Comment: @Nikita okay, I tend to agree the name isn't perfect. I changed it to `ToSelectionWith(pageSize)`, which I think is slightly more descriptive and less misleading. The point of an abstraction, though, is to keep this implemention detail hidden away.

Comment: It is indeed. That is why the name should be descriptive enough, to call the method _readable_. I do not suggest to call it `ToSortedSetWith()` or something (though i would consider something along these lines), i merely point out that its name (at least the old one) does not reflect what this method actually does.

Comment: +1 for favoring readability of business logic over total LOC. I also liked using a method to replace an idiom, namely `Concat(new{...})`. However `Selection` has no inherent meaning. Also result being a sorted set is not really an *implementation detail*, as it being a distinct and ordered collection is a requirement. How about refactoring your `ToSelectionWith` to SRP methods like `someEnumerable.Append(someValue, someOtherValue).ToSortedSet()`. With `ToSortedSet` being a least surprise counterpart to `ToArray` and `ToList`.

Comment: Using a sorted set is a good idea. But `ToSelectionWith` is badly named and nothing more than `UnionAndSort`, so it's an SRP violation as well.

Answer (score 8):

Size of initial list in the following code is less:

```
var x = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                  .Select(x_ => x_ * 10)
                  .Concat(new[] {25})
                  .Distinct()
                  .OrderBy(x_ => x_)
                  .ToList();
```

Otherwise your original code is perfect.

Comment: Where is this `x_` notation coming from? I have never seen it in C#.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking `Range` does not create list. Your version does require less iterations nonetheless and is easier to read.

Comment: This is the coding convention that I follow. x_ is used for input parameters and _x is that is used for member variables.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak: `x_` is just a variable name, nothing special.

Comment: @Chris, well, obviously. I was asking what naming convention is that (as it contradicts msdn guidelines for parametrs).

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak: In that case sorry for what may have come across as a very patronizing comment.

Comment: You can collapse `Concat(...).Distinct` into `Union`

Answer (score 5):

Just include the custom value in the condition, then you don't need to concatentat it, remove duplicates or sort. To get the range from 10 to 100 you should use 91 as count in the `Range` method, `Range(10, 100)` creates numbers from 10 to 109.

```
var pageSize = 25;

var items =
  Enumerable.Range(10, 91)           
  .Where(x => x % 10 == 0 || x == pageSize);
```

Note: This naturally only works if the custom value is inside the range.

Comment: This is a neat way. Unfortunately the `pageSize` could be outside of the range.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't much left to add to the actual use case OP mentioned, considering the general problem of **inserting a value in the correct order in an ordered sequence**, a more time and space efficient solution exists.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertPreservingOrder<T> (this IEnumerable<T> sortedSequence, T value)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return sortedSequence.TakeWhile(x => x.CompareTo(value) < 0)
             .Append(value)
             .Concat(sortedSequence.SkipWhile(x => x.CompareTo(value) <= 0));
}
```

where `Append` is syntactic sugar for `.Concat(new{...})` [as per @codesparkle's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47423/20251):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, params T[] items)
{
    return sequence.Concat(items);
}
```

This operation is of constant (O(1)) space, linear (O(n)) time and lazy.
Especially useful in situations like this :

```
var customValue = 15;
var defaultValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(x_ => x_ * 10);
var items = defaultValues.InsertPreservingOrder(customValue);
// then later
items.Take(10).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

I also think this method is a clear improvement in capturing programmer's intent w.r.t. the original version, regardless of asymptotic complexity.
It reifies an idea; therefore can be reused, whenever the current value of a variable would be added in a collection of default options. Its name makes clear both the precondition that first parameter is assumed to be already sorted, and the postcondition that the return value is also sorted. However it leaves the distinctness condition opaque.

Though I'd still prefer a simple [`defaultValues.Append(customValue).ToSortedSet()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/generate-sequence-in-linq#comment83136_47423)